# PHP показывает старый url, как пофиксить?

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс, url

Вообщем в зависимости нажат ли чекбокс в JS прокидываю параметр в url, а в PHP меняю значение переменной в зависимости от url.Все работает хорошо, кроме того что PHP опоздывает на один рендер!Например есть url: http://ru.stackoverflow.com и при нажатии чекбокса прокидывается параметр ts=true, страница перезагружается и получается http://ru.stackoverflow.com?ts=true .
А эхо в PHP показывает http://ru.stackoverflow.com если если снять чекбокс, тем самым убрав параметр из url то url в браузере будет http://ru.stackoverflow.com а эхо в PHP покажет http://ru.stackoverflow.com?ts=true

Код PHP:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo $url;
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
if ($query['ts'] == true) {
    $CHECK_DATES = 'N';
} else {
    $CHECK_DATES = 'Y';
}
?>
```

Ну и это все происходит в битриксе, где как раз таки $CHECK_DATES один из параметров компонента, но думаю что это никак не влияет на этот баг.

Ну и как собственно получить в PHP актуальный url тот же который в браузере?

Буду благодарен все откликнувшимся!

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` содержит `url` с которого был сделан запрос.

Вам нужны параметры `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` и `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php